# Selling a product using Arduino microcontroller or bootloader

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide

I was wondering if I am legally allowed to sell an Arduino based product.  I also want to know if it is easy for people to retrieve code from an Arduino based circuit (reverse engineer it) or upload code from Arduino microcontrollers.

If I'm posting in the wrong please, please let me know. If there is better place to redirect my question, letting me know would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino hardware is released under the creative commons license.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ#toc3

"which allows for both personal and commercial derivative works, as long as they credit Arduino and release their designs under the same license"

It's possible for someone to retrieve the instructions from the MCU but they would be looking at assembly rather than the c code you wrote your sketch in.

This is a similar question and answer:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/can-arduino-be-used-in-commercial-products

Comment: And what of the Arduino *software* ?  Also, your comment about retrieving information from the MCU is only *conditionally* accurate.